# windows batch ignores if else

Tags: windows, batch-file

my Batch script just seems to jump over my if else part... or maybe it just dies... i dunno...

why is that?

```
@echo on
echo Welche URL soll in Chrome geoeffnet werden? (Enter = lamp.dev)
echo Die URL bitte ohne http/https
echo.
set /p url=URL: 
pause
IF %url="" (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://lamp.dev --new-window "https://lamp.dev"
)ELSE(
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://%url% --new-window "https://%url%"
)
pause
```

Comment: Variables need to be enclosed in percent signs, not just a leading one. The equal comparison operator is `==`. If one side is quoted the other needs also quoting. Better use `if defined url` to test if a var is set. Else needs spaces around it `) ELSE (`. Without being firm with the syntax your title doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify it like this:

```bat
@echo off
echo Welche URL soll in Chrome geoeffnet werden? (Enter = lamp.dev)
echo Die URL bitte ohne http/https
echo.
set /p url=URL: 
pause
IF NOT DEFINED url SET "url=lamp.dev"
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://%url% --new-window "https://%url%"
pause
```

Comment: suggest putting quotes around set variable or one may be surprised with the blank spaces: `set /p "url=URL: "`

Comment: Although recommended it's not necessary to the OP's code. The OP already included an intended single space at the end, so on a default size cmd window a few unintended whitespaces after the prompt shouldn't cause harm.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are referenced by enclosing them in `%`. Instead of `%url=""` use `"%url%"==""`

Additionally you should enclose the `set /p` command with quotes to show the whitespace at the end, and use `if not defined url` to check if a variable is defined.

```
@echo off
echo Welche URL soll in Chrome geoeffnet werden? (Enter = lamp.dev)
echo Die URL bitte ohne http/https
echo.
set /p "url=URL: "
if not defined url (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://lamp.dev --new-window "https://lamp.dev"
) else (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://%url% --new-window "https://%url%"
)
```

Comment: You replaced the first of them within the quick edit window so that it doesn't show and the other one later, so they are now both fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For your if statement, since it is a string variable, you need to enclose the if in parentheses. You also forgot to add the closing %

```
set /p url=URL: 
pause
IF "%url%"="" (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://lamp.dev --new-window "https://lamp.dev"
)ELSE(
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://%url% --new-window "https://%url%"
)
pause
```

Hope this helps